# GWT Server-Side Code not working in production mode

Tags: gwt, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

THis is my first attempt to deploy a GWT application with a significant amount of serverside functionality - so I may be doing something dumb.

I cannot get my GWT web application work in production mode. It works fine in the development mode, but when I upload the compiled .war file to Elastic Beanstalk and try and run the program the serverside code fails.

I get the following browser error:

--
[16:07:33.342] POST http://campusmap.elasticbeanstalk.com/qmap/sside [HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error 106ms]

I have compiled my project using an ant script based this tutorial:
http://www.rubiconred.com/blog/build-package-a-gwt-app-to-war-using-ant/

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"  
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" version="2.5">
    <!-- TODO: Add <servlet> tags for each servlet here. -->
    <!-- TODO: Add <servlet-mapping> tags for each <servlet> here. -->
    <!-- TODO: Optionally add a <welcome-file-list> tag to display a welcome file. -->
<!-- Default page to serve -->
  <!-- Servlets -->
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>serverSide</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.qmap.core.server.ServerSideImpl</servlet-class>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>serverSide</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/qmap/sside</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>    


  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

</web-app>
```

Any help or pointers would be much appreciated.

Comment: 500 Internal Server Error probably means that your Servlet throws an unexpected exception, but impossible to tell without a stacktrace.

Comment: Get the stacktrace from your logs. No one can help you until you do.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, had no access to log files  - so set up tomcat on local server, deployed war file and was able to debug using the stack trace.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this issue by removing web app from elasticbeanstalk and running it on a dedicated apache server - this allowed me to get acces to log files and stack traces and I was able to resolve the problem. The precise error was an incorrect uri within my code with relation to the apache server.